# Upgrade Azure.Messaging.EventHubs from 5.5.0 to 5.9.0. When I use 'eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset' return error

Tags: azure, upgrade, azure-eventhub

Upgrade Azure.Messaging.EventHubs from 5.5.0 to 5.9.0.

I need to change old Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData to Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData.

But when I use :

```
var decompressed = Decompress(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);
```

The Decompress function is :

```
public static string Decompress(byte[] input, int offset, int count)
    {
        // GZip
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(input, offset, count);
        using var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

return: 'ReadOnlyMemory' does not contain a definition for 'Array' and no accessible extension method 'Array' accepting a first argument of type 'ReadOnlyMemory' could be found
[image]

I think the new version EventData.Body was changed, but I don't know the new alternative functions.
What is the new functions replace the 'eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count'? How to find it?

Comment: Because the ReadOnlyMemory type doesn't have an Array attribute, you are seeing an error notice. In Azure's most recent iteration.Messaging.EventHubs, the BinaryData type describes the Body attribute of the event data. The ToArray() method of the BinaryData object allows access to its underlying bytes.

Comment: Here is an example of how to modify your Decompress function to work with the new version of Azure.Messaging.EventHubs - public static string Decompress(BinaryData input)
{
    // GZip
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(input.ToArray());
    using var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

Comment: Then call the decompress function liike here -var decompressed = Decompress(eventData.Body);

Comment: You can find information about eventdata constructors here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata?view=azure-dotnet#constructors

Answer (score 1):

***You can wrap event data object in an array list and then use EventHubProducer client to send the data like below:-***

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Replace the <EVENT_HUBS_CONNECTION_STRING> and <EVENT_HUB_NAME> placeholder values
            var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://eventhub1.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKeyxxxxxxx+AEhLwhfnY=";
            var eventHubName = "siliconeventhub";

            // Create a new EventHubProducerClient object
            await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName))
            {
                // Create a batch of events
                using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

                // Add events to the batch
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    var eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Event {i}"));
                    eventBatch.TryAdd(eventData);
                }

                // Send the batch of events to the event hub
                await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Event Sent:-**

[image]

***Now use the code below to receive the event and decompress it:-***

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Replace the <EVENT_HUBS_CONNECTION_STRING> and <EVENT_HUB_NAME> placeholder values
            var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://eventhub1.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxx+AEhLwhfnY=";
            var eventHubName = "siliconeventhub";

            // Create a new EventHubConsumerClient object
            await using (var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName, connectionString, eventHubName))
            {
                // Receive events from the event hub
                await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync())
                {
                    // Decompress the body of the event
                    var decompressed = Decompress(BinaryData.FromBytes(partitionEvent.Data.Body));

                    // Print the decompressed body of the event
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received event: {decompressed}");
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Decompress(BinaryData input)
        {
            // Check if the data is GZIP-compressed
            if (IsGZipCompressed(input.ToArray()))
            {
                using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(input.ToArray());
                using var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                using var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream, Encoding.UTF8);

                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                // Treat the data as plain text if it's not GZIP-compressed
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input.ToArray());
            }
        }

        private static bool IsGZipCompressed(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data.Length < 2)
                return false;

            return data[0] == 31 && data[1] == 139;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]